# Cannot resolve maps symbol

Tags: android, maps

I'm trying to use google maps in my app but it doesnt recognize the 'maps' when I'm trying to import the package. I get the error "cannot resolve symbol maps". I installed the google apis from my sdk verson but still i can't find the solution to this problem.

```
package com.example.app_silvia;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;




public class Reporte3Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ManejoSesion session;
    private MapView mapa;
    private MapController controlMapa;
    private Button boton;
    private EditText input;
    private String direccion;
    private List <Address> address;



}
```

This is my `manifest.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.app_silvia">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />
    <protected-broadcast android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/api" />
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity"
            android:label="@string/registername"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".ReporteActivity"
            android:label="@string/reportename"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".Reporte2Activity"
            android:label="@string/reportename"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

and this is my `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app_silvia"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You'll be more likely to attract help if you could rework your code to a [mcve]. Basically make it as short as possible while still demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In AndroidManifest.xml, add the following element as a child of the `<application>` element, by inserting it just before the closing `</application>` tag:

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="YOUR_API_KEY"/>
```

And also provide permissions.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

In your `XML` layout file add google map fragment.

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

Then in your maps activity inside `onCreate` override method add the following code.

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }
```

For further understanding see in [android developer documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/start).

Comment: The problem is that i have done all that, but the error still persists. I thinks is maybe the gradle or the sdk but i'm not sure what could be.

Comment: have you added this in build.gradle ?

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0'